# Why doesn't join() automatically convert its arguments to strings? When would you ever not want them to be strings?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

We have a list:

```
myList = [1, "two"]
```

And want to print it out, normally I would use something like:

```
"{0} and {1}".format(*myList)
```

But you could also do:

```
" and ".join(myList)
```

But unfortunately:

```
>>> " and ".join(myList)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

Why doesn't it just automatically convert the list it receives to strings?

When would you ever not need it to convert them to strings? Is there some tiny edge case I'm missing?

Comment: `import this`: Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

and

> Errors should never pass silently.

Converting to strings implicitly can easily hide bugs, and I'd really want to know if I suddenly have different types somewhere that were meant to be strings.

If you want to explicitly convert to strings, you can do so using `map()`, for example:

```
''.join(map(str, myList))
```

Comment: Nice answer, but does "Explicit is better than implicit" really follow around all of python? .sorted() for example defaults to ascending, first element

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: no, `list.sort()` defaults to using comparisons. It's up to the objects in the sequence what that means. For strings and tuples and lists, that's lexicographical, ascending.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: And there are plenty of mistakes in Python 2 that have been corrected in Python 3. Implicit conversions between `str` and `unicode` for example. And a default ordering when sorting between disparate types cannot really be compared.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: The Zen is a philosophy, a northern star to strive for. Yes, there are spots in the Python language that don't quite reach that, but `str.join()` does adhere to it.

Comment: I think of this as "explicit > implicit" + "special cases aren't special enough to break the rules".  In this *particular* case, converting to `str` wouldn't have been the worst thing ever, but keeping the number of implicit coercions to a minimum is also an important goal.  (On practicality grounds you can pry 1 + 1.5 from me out of my cold, dead hands, but we needn't multiply such cases.)

Comment: @DSM: I actually considered quoting *special cases* here too but I didn't want to get into an argument how `str.join()` is not a special case - *sure it is* - no it's not, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with attempting to execute something like `x = 4 + "8"` as written is that the intended meaning is ambiguous. Should `x` contain `"48"` (implicitly converting `4` to `str`) or `12` (implicitly converting `"8"` to `int`)? We can't justify either result.

To avoid this confusion, Python requires explicit conversion of one of the operands:

```
>>> x = str(4) + "8"
>>> y = 4 + int("8")
>>> print x
48
>>> print y
12
```

Comment: +1 for a practical justification for requiring explicit argument conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is sort-of irrelevant as join() is about specifying a string to concatenate list items with, which doesn't leave this ambiguity.

Comment: It's still going to be attempting `1 + " and " + "two"` under the covers though, right? Using `mylist = [str(1), "two"]` allows the concatenation to work.

Comment: This makes sense for the `+` operator, but `str.join` is a method of the `str` type and clearly isn't meant to operate on anything besides strings. So there is no confusion if you just convert everything to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Using the correct type is part of programming in Python. A general built-in like `print` does do the conversion (if the class supports `__str__`), which is where you should be doing it:

Let `print` do the work:

```
print(*myList, sep = " and ")
```

That's for Python 3, if you are still on Python 2 then use:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Python is not strongly typed, it's not Java (thank god!).  Join should be able to handle anything that with a __str__ method and use it.  There's no ambiguity there.

Comment: Print is a function that prints stuff to a file or iostream, it doesn't generate a string, which is what I want if I'm using str.join.